# My Excel files keep getting numbers added to the file name even when my pc is closed down. Any ideas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Even when my pc is shutdown my spreadsheet that is used on a daily basis gets a number added to the file name. This seems to happen randomly but it does increase every few days. I can reset the file name but it just starts again. Any help to understand this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it just a number? Or a `(1)`, etc.?

Comment: Did you have use any VBA macro for Workbook Load event, Or What formula has been used to add numbers??

Comment: Does the Excel file was renamed to a duplicate copy automatically?

Comment: Is the file saved on a server or on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your machine is getting shut down with Excel still opened.

When you reopen excel the next day - it pulls up a recovery version. That you then start working on and save as FILENAME(1).xlsx.

If it's not that... I'm at a loss.